# How can I access the remote clipboard when Screen Sharing into a Linux system

Tags: macos, screen-sharing

I am using Screen Sharing to do vnc to my work computer running Linux, 
however the Edit -> Cut,Copy, Paste,Delete commands are all greyed out. 
Is there some way to enable these options ?

On a related question, I could get text from one vnc window to the clipboard when highlighted with the mouse, and can paste to the same vnc window, but I can't paste the same text to another vnc window... as if the clipboard isn't updating. Seems each vnc window remembers its own clipboard updates only, 
which is not what I want. Would prefer clipboard info to be available to
all vnc windows, is this possible ?

Comment: Usually it's better to only ask one question in one post, but in your case they are obviously related. My guess would be that remote clipboard access is not compatible between the VNC server running on your Linux machine and Screen Sharing.

Comment: clipboard cut and paste does work well with the windows version... i'll just have to stick with this for now (or write my own app for this :)) thnx.

Answer (score 2):

There's a program called `vncconfig` that makes clipboard integration work. Just run it in your sever like:

```
vncconfig &
```

And now it works. Kind of a miserably named program though. Another tip is to add `vncconfig &` to your `~/.vnc/xstartup` script so you always have it.

Comment: More info about enabling clipboard via vncconfig in Superuser StackExchange: http://superuser.com/questions/376877/copy-paste-clipboard-like-functionality-from-a-vnc-desktop. Also vncconfig+autocutsel in Unix StackExchange: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/35046.

Comment: I don't have this on the server. I use tightvnc.